# How does $xy^0z = λ$ not contradict $y \ne λ$ in the pumping lemma?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, pumping-lemma

I have just started out theory of automata in my university and we are studying the pumping lemma.
From what I have understood, the lemma states that $y \neq \lambda$ (where $\lambda$ is the empty string) and that $xy^iz$ (where $i \ge 0$), so if $i = 0$ then $y^0 = \lambda$ and the string is still accepted.

How do these not contradict each other? If $i = 0$, then $y$ becomes the empty string that is previously stated cannot be empty? Please explain.

Comment: "If $i=0$, $y$ becomes the empty string..." Not so. $y^0$ is the empty string, but that's not $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example. Consider the regular language consisting of all words over $\{0,1\}$ with an even number of $0$s and $1$s. It has a pumping constant of at most $4$.

Let's pick a word in this language: $0110$.

We can write it in the form $xyz$, where $x=\lambda$, $y = 0110$, $z = \lambda$.

Then:

- $xy^0z = \lambda$.
- $xy^1z = 0110$.
- $xy^2z = 01100110$.
- $xy^3z = 011001100110$.

And so on. All of these words are in the language, and in fact $xy^i z$ is in the language for all $i \ge 0$.

The pumping lemma states that for every regular language there is a constant $n$ such that every word in the language of length at least $n$ has such a decomposition $xyz$, where moreover $|xy| \leq n$ and $y \neq \lambda$.

As you can see, $x,y,z$ are the parts into which the original word is decomposed. When we look at $xy^iz$, the strings $x,y,z$ don't change at all.